# How to resize the image in better way using PHP?

Tags: php, image-resizing

I want to resize the image without affecting its quality using PHP.When I trying to do with imagick or GD library in PHP if I give the fixed width or height its going to be affect the quality of image.So when I try with some other sites they are doing like depend upon the image size they dynamically resize the images.ie if I upload image in two different size when re-sizing both the images contains different width and height .But in my application when I give the thumbnail width 640(both imagic and GD library) then I will get the images with 640 image size.I want to know how do they dynamically calculate the image width and height for resizing?And also when resizing very low size image how can I achieve the quality?

Comment: this is elentary shcool math, dude.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image while resizing it, you can keep only one of the width or height as constant while other one you need to calculate based on the aspect ratio.

For example if you want to make the image width as 640, you can find the targetHeight using following formulta

```
targetHeight = sourceHeight/sourceWidth * 640;
```

Comment: @guru-But in that site they changed the re-sizing into dynamically.Both height and width are dynamic.Site is Zoomin.com.How do they do it.I want to o in the same way for resize image.I need  a logic

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to find a way to resize in PHP without loosing aspect ratio? Or you want to copy the way a site does dynamic resizing??  Dynamic resizing requires a lot of client javascript for creating an interface where user can specify either the width or height , and other one is calculated based on that keeping the aspect ratio same using the formula above